# TIR in helm doesn't give +2 mana after kill

Tags: diablo-ii

I put a TIR rune into a double socketed cap and equipped the cap on my assassin. When I use wake of fire, I get no mana back for kills.  Is there any reason for this?  Does each kill have to be done with a spell or melee for the +2 to mana, so traps don't count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Arreat Summit](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/skills/assassin-traps.shtml):

> Traps function as golems and summons

Also, from [this page](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Mana):

> "Points of Mana After Each Kill" (prefixes Triumphant, Victorious) provides a small amount of mana every time the player kills an enemy. Any type of damage inflicted by the player works, kills by minions do not.

So traps damage doesn't count as player's damage and effect doesn't work.